# Windows: Any virtual desktop manager that uses desktop objects?

Tags: windows, virtual-desktop-manager

Most virtual desktop managers for Windows simulate multiple desktops by hiding some windows and bringing others to the top.

Is there any virtual desktop manager for Windows that creates a different **desktop object** for each virtual desktop?

Comment: I'm not sure what is wrong with hiding the windows.  You are less likely to lose the windows if the desktop manager crashes.

Comment: Surfasb: A manager that uses desktop objects is more robust and less likely to crash.

Comment: Supposedly.  My theory is a well written manager is more robust and less likely to crash. It's one thing to say your design is more robust. It is another when thousands of users say your program is robust.  This object thing sounds like a wash. . .

Comment: Even sysInternals provides a list of gotchas.  I'd stick with a VDM that is more widely used and more updated.  The big gotcha is if Desktop gets corrupted, you gotta logoff. . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[nSpaces](http://www.bytesignals.com/nspaces/)** is another virtual desktop manager which uses desktop objects.

It has a bit more features than SysInternals Desktops, like configurable keyboard shortcuts, colors and wallpapers. However, it suffers the same limitations like Desktops.

Answer (score 6):

Sysinternals' [Desktops](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc817881.aspx) does that.

> Unlike other virtual desktop utilities that implement their desktops by showing the windows that are active on a desktop and hiding the rest, **Sysinternals Desktops uses a Windows desktop object for each desktop.**

Comment: Sysinternals Desktops has a few problems. For example, it cannot use Aero on desktops 2-4. Is there any other desktop manager that uses desktop objects?

Comment: it also doesn't work with wacom graphics tablet pen on desktop 2-4. i also can't seem to launch chrome because it thinks it's already open

Answer (score -3):

Why not switch to Linux and virtualize Windows using Virtual Box?  I am SURE, this is what you are really looking for: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7BtpNRgAERE

Comment: This I cannot do right now. Sorry! :-)